# Vertices are hidden by mesh when using Subdivision modifier

Tags: mesh

I am having a problem whenever I am in edit mode working on the mesh some of the vertices hide behind the mesh like this

[image]

and it creates some problems so what I want my mesh to look like when in edit mode to be like this [image]
I've taken this picture from the blender guru video.

Thanks for hearing about my problem.

P.S: when I zoom out it seems to show those vertices

Answer (score 1):

You must have a *Subdivision Surface* modifier, this modifier adds virtual faces in order to round the shape, and therefore it deforms the appearance of the surface, that's why it may hide some of your vertices if they are in concave parts:

[image]

If you enable the modifier's *On Cage* option you'll see the vertex as it is if the modifier is applied, but it won't appear at its exact current place:

[image]

You can also enable the *X-Ray* display option with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> but you'll also see the opposite vertices:

[image]

Or simply disable the modifier's visibility.

Comment: thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Have you added a subdivision surface modifier to your mesh?

If you have then it is really simple
[image]

simply enable the on cage option(the triangle)

Then your hidden vertices will be shown!

[image]
**This image is without the option enabled**

***HOPE THIS HELPED!***

Comment: thanks its working now